# Android indeterminate ProgressBar is not animating

Tags: android

The strange situation I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/my_progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the result is [image]

The ProgressBar is not animating. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I dropped your ProgressBar element into an existing linear layout of mine & it animates without needing to do anything else.  Have you tried to clean & rebuild the project?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For future searches. It was pretty easy and pretty hard to find the mistake.

Just make sure, that your animations are **ENABLED** in phone developer options.

Comment: I have the exact same problem but I have checked and animations ARE enabled in my phone's developer options. Hmm...

Comment: One of the dumbest mistakes I ever made. I was writing a same project for my UI test setup. And animations were disabled on my emulator.

Answer (score -1):

When I run the App on emulator, the animation does not work. But if I switch to a real device, the bar spins.